# Function callback in directive with original binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Passing in a function to be called back on init to a directive, this function is noted by a string attribute which is then parsed and used. The issue is when used, the function binding is no longer attached/bound to the object the function is part of. Here is what I mean ([see on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Frdj09P0Iq6XRPnP7Qr))

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.13"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.container = {
    x: null
  , setup: function(x){
      console.log(this); //this here should be $scope.container, but its window
      this.x = x;
    }
  };
});

app.directive('dir', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E'
  , transclude: false
  , scope: true
  , link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var callback = attrs.setup
        , someCalcVar = 10
        ;
      $parse(callback)(scope)(someCalcVar);
    }
  };
}]);

</script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>container.x == '{{container.x}}'</p>
  <dir setup="container.setup"></dir>
</body>

</html>
```

is there a way to achieve what I want? Perhaps there is a better way to design this but still keep some sort of container for the callback and related variables?

Edit:

A naive win could be to check if the callback has a `dot` and then bind it manually using `func.bind(substr(callback, ...))` ... is there something builtin to angular that would do this? alternatively is there a cleaner approach to all this?

Comment: Maybe something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/S461ZpcWXX2wq0AIQx2n?p=preview

Comment: @AlexandrinRus the problem with that is the directive has to know about `container` which is not something that it would normally need to know about / enforce

Comment: For the easy win, use ng-init. Just say ng-init="container.setup()"

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most elegant solution but you could always just create a function that wraps up calling setup on container:

```
$scope.callableSetup = function(x) {
    $scope.container.setup(x);  
}
```

Comment: this works, that is true, but as you said, not the most elegant. Still holding out for something really nice :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting [one possible solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/cjfzxyxpZ0YAhtAcJpcS?p=preview), using underscorejs bind, I can enforce this in the controller

```
$scope.container.setup = _.bind($scope.container.setup, $scope.container);
```

still not the elegance I am looking for, still waiting for the knight in shining armor of an answer

Edit: the [guys over @goinstant](https://twitter.com/goinstant/status/439885140219527168) have a [similar solution requiring underscore's bind technique but is more elegant](http://plnkr.co/edit/07dgYt2OtqwoIcnUISZY?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var that = this;
$scope.container = {
    x: null,
    setup: function(x) {
        console.log(that); //this here should be $scope.container, but its window
        console.log(x);
        that.x = x;
    }
};
```

Comment: shouldn't `that=$scope.container` rather than `this`?

Comment: this is the controller it's a reference

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
var self;
$scope.container = self = {
    x: null, 
    setup: function(x) {
        console.log(this);
        self.x = x;
    }
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/xtDWc5jyaayvTWgFrXaw?p=preview